# Add Ant Library Project into my Gradle project

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I have a Gradle Android project, which includes an Ant library project: https://github.com/pakerfeldt/android-viewflow.

How can I include this Ant library project in my build.gradle file?  I tried to added "ant.importBuild 'lib/viewflow/build.xml'"  but didn't work.

Is there anything missing or mistake here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a similar question to [android-studio-library-not-recognizing-the-android-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23973156/android-studio-library-not-recognizing-the-android-api).

In the viewflow directory you'll need to create a build.gradle file with the following content:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.10.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-library'

android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }
    }

    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
}
```

You have the option of including the generated AAR file into your project's libs folder like the linked question or you can copy the viewflow project into your projects root directory and include it as a module by modifying your settings.gradle and adding it your project's dependency section using **compile project**:

```
compile project(':viewflow')
```

Comment: You are a super star :)