# Android Studio: Library not recognizing the Android API

Tags: gradle, android-studio

I am trying to add [this](https://github.com/kodart/Httpzoid) library to my project.  I put the files from GitHub in my `libraries` directory under my project's default module folder.

When I first added the library, it wasn't recognized in my project until I changed the the folder structure from `httpzoid/src/` to `httpzoid/src/main/java`.

At this point I am able to import classes from the library.  The only problem is, Android components such as `android.content.Context` aren't recognized by the library, so it basically doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The project does not have a Ant or Gradle build file so need to create one.

First you will need to delete the local.properties since it references the developers local sdk directory. Then create a file named build.gradle in the projects directory with the following content.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.10.+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-library'

android {

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }
    }

    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
}
```

Then in command line go to the projects root directory and run "gradle build". This will generate the file "Httpzoid.aar" in the projects build/libs directory. Copy this file into your main project's libs folder.

You'll now be able to add it as a dependency by modifying your project's build.gradle file and adding the following:

```
dependencies {
    repositories {
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }

    compile(name:'Httpzoid', ext:'aar')
}
```

As an aside, have you considered using [Retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit) or [Ion](https://github.com/koush/ion) as an alternative REST client? These two excellent libraries have similar callback mechanisms and both are actively updated (Last update for HttpZoid was July 22, 2013). Also they are both on Maven Central.

Comment: Thank you.  I was able to get Httpzoid to work, but I ended up going with Ion